# Assigning values to imported variables from excel

Tags: excel, import, wolfram-mathematica, variable-assignment

I need to import an excel document into mathematica which has 2000 compounds in it, with each compound have 6 numerical constants assigned to it. The end goal is to type a compound name into mathematica and have the 6 numerical constants be outputted. So far my code is:

t = Import["Titles.txt.", {"Text", "Lines"}] (*imports compound names*)
n = Import["NA.txt.", "List"] (*imports the 6 values for each compound*)

n[[2]] (*outputs the second compounds 6 values*)

Instead of n[[#]] i would like to know how to type in a compound from the imported compound names and have the 6 values be outputted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question - you have two text files, rather than an Excel file, for example, and it's not clear what the data looks like. But there are probably plenty of ways to do this. Here's a suggestion (it might not be the best way):

Let's assume that you've got all your data into a table (a list of lists):

```mathematica
pt = {
 {"Hydrogen", "H", 1, 1.0079, -259, -253, 0.09, 0.14, 1776, 1, 13.5984},
 {"Helium", "He", 2, 4.0026, -272, -269, 0, 0, 1895, 18, 24.5874},
 {"Lithium" , "Li", 3, 6.941, 180, 1347, 0.53, 0, 1817, 1, 5.3917}
 }
```

To find the information associated with a particular string:

```
Cases[pt, {"Helium", rest__} -> rest]
```

> {"He", 2, 4.0026, -272, -269, 0, 0, 1895, 18, 24.5874}

where the pattern `rest__` holds everything that was found after "Helium".

To look for the second item:

```
 Cases[pt, {_, "Li", rest__} -> rest]
```

> {2, 4.0026, -272, -269, 0, 0, 1895, 18, 24.5874}

If you add more information to the patterns, you have more flexibility in how you choose elements from the table:

```
Cases[pt, {name_, symbol_, aNumber_, aWeight_, mp_, bp_, density_, 
           crust_, discovered_, rest__} 
      /; discovered > 1850  -> {name, symbol, discovered}]
```

> {{"Helium", "He", 1895}}

For something interactive, you could knock up a `Manipulate`:

```
elements = pt[[All, 1]];
headings = {"symbol", "aNumber", "aWeight", "mp", "bp", "density", "crust", "discovered", "group", "ion"};
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   elements[[x]],
   TableForm[{
     headings, Cases[pt, {elements[[x]], rest__} -> rest]}]}],
{x, 1, Length[elements], 1}]
```

[image: interactive]

Comment: @KateMcCallum cool, feel free to upvote, accept, etc. :) Better Mathematica advice can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Is there a way to modify the line /; discovered > 1850  so one could pick a specific name instead of value range?                                                              Cases[pt, {name_, symbol_, aNumber_, aWeight_, mp_, bp_, density_, 
           crust_, discovered_, rest__} 
      /; discovered > 1850  -> {name, symbol, discovered}]

Comment: @Kate The `/; x > y` is a conditional pattern. If true, the replacement (pattern -> replacement pattern) is made. So try `name == "Helium"` (double equals)...

Comment: great that worked perfect i forgot about the need of quotations thank you so much for you help!